# JSON format - Getting KeyError 'response'

Tags: python, json

```py
street_info.append(json_here_response['response']['route'][0]['leg'][0]['link'][0]['functionalClass'])
```

There is a KeyError for 'response'. Probably  a problem with the JSON formatting and the new version for indexing

Comment: What does the response look like? Apparently it's not like you think

Comment: Try printing `json_here_response`.